# using map to autogenerate table rows with map in react causes error when handling a click event

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to create an auto-generated table with rows that can be clicked. When a user clicks the row, a change event handler is fired that copies the data clicked in the row to another table for selected items.

The list generates fine but when I click the row, react bring up the error: **TypeError: that.state.orderlist.map is not a function**

Below is the react component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

class OrderTable extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let that = this.props.that;
  return (
    <Table striped hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Food Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {that.state.orderlist.map((name, index) =>
        <tr key={index} onClick={() => that.onResultClick(name)}><td>{name.id}</td><td>{name.fooditem}</td><td>{name.price}</td></tr>

      )}
      {console.log(JSON.stringify(that.state.orderlist))}
      </tbody>
  </Table>

  );
  }
}
export default OrderTable;
```

The `orderlist` state code is below:

```
this.state = {
              orderlist: [{id: '1', vegetable: 'kales', price: '20'},{id: '2', fooditem: 'cabbages', price: '20'}]

            };
```

`OrderTable` is then called as a component in another component in which I have the following code:

```
<OrderTable that={this}/>
```

Comment: is `state.orderlist` belongs to `OrderTable` where are you initiate it?

Comment: state.orderlist is initiated in a different component that implements OrderTable. In the other component I have <OrderTable that={this} />

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do but this is not a way to pass in a prop. why don't you just pass it like that `<OrderTable myList={this.state.orderlist}/>` and then inside `OrderTable` you can acces it like this: `this.props.myList` (or whatever prop name you like)

Comment: I'm calling the onClick handler inside OrderTable so I decide to pass the whole _this_ as prop - I didn't know better way to do it. Yet my problem still remain: ...order list.map is not a function when onClick event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

After racking my brain a few hours about this strange behavior, It turns out that the map function and everything worked fine except for the event handler: `onResultClick` which was changing the state of `orderlist`. So the code posted above had no problem.

Apparently the handler changed the type of `state.orderlist` from an array to an object by replacing it with an object instead of concatenating or pushing:  `this.setState( {orderlist: data})` instead of `this.setState( {orderlist: this.state.orderlist.concat(data)}` . By changing orderlist to an object (i.e {x:y}), the map function was inaccessible.

Anyone having similar problem should also have a look at their implementation of setState method.